# innerHtml not working on extension popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm updating a div with some html inside a chrome extension with innerHtml but nothing changes, however, if checking the innerHtml of the same element via console its the expected one, if checking the innerText returns the initial value, am I doing something wrong??

This is what I do to update:

```
document.getElementById("ID").innerHtml = "<p>Error.</p>";
```

This is what is returned in console:

```
> document.getElementById("ID").innerHtml
> "<p>Error.</p>"
> document.getElementById("ID").innerText
> "Loading...."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property is actually called [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) (note the capitalization of "HTML"). Are you setting the right one?

Comment: Whaaat? Since when do you have to capitalize HTML in innerHtml? I'm not a JS guru, but I didn't think I was this much of a noob. Is this something new?